# dynamically import submodules in python

Tags: python, import, imp

Suppose I provide a module in the command line and want to import it using the "imp" module:

```
$ foo.py mod.a.b.c
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Split the "mod.a.b.c" and add each path? The behaviour of "imp" does not seem to be parallel to "import".

Answer (score 5):

Given a module path as a string (`modulename`), you can import it with

```
module = __import__(modulename,fromlist='.')
```

Note that `__import__('mod.a.b.c')` returns the package `mod`, while `__import__('mod.a.b.c',fromlist='.')` returns the module `mod.a.b.c`.